# how to get no of dates appear between Fromdt to Todt and fetching thouse dates in column

Tags: sql-server, date, recursive-query

![enter image description here][1]

I have table called `tbl_monthly_leave`

in below table i am trying to take dates between fromdt to Todate like (Fromdt , Todate) as number of leaves date applied for, collect all dates in one single column leavedapplieddates.
i am trying to match Emp_no to range of dates.
For example
If one employee apply leaves for 5 days
He will select fromdt as 20-07-2020 and Todt has 25-07-2020, number of level applied days is 5, now I am stuck to iterate dates, required output is
20-07-2020
21-07-2020
22-07-2020
23-07-2020
24-07-2020.

I am applying one more logic
for ex if
Sunday and Saturday come need to filter , after filtering number dates will become 3, applied leave count will be 3 dates

Comment: It is totally unclear what you mean by this question, and it more unclear why @Adyson is not asking for more details.....

Comment: @Luuk I just edited it to be helpful. It's not a question that particularly interests me personally right now. What's even more puzzling really is why the OP has managed to edit it so as to destroy the formatting again and yet still failed to provide more info in the process :-(

Comment: maybe the question should closed, due to the low quality , like inconsistency between column names, and the 6 (or 7) edit's, which is WAY to many, because the question is till no clear.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a recursive query.

Assuming that you are running SQL Sever (because you tagged your question `sql` and `server`, which is quite common pattern of SO newcomers), that would be:

```
with leaves as (
    select emp_no, leave_appl_dt, from_dt, to_dt 
    from tbl_monthly_leaves
    union all
    select emp_no, leave_appl_dt, dateadd(day, 1, from_dt), to_dt
    from leaves
    where from_dt < to_dt
)
select from_dt leave_dt, emp_no, leave_appl_dt from leaves order by emp_no, leave_dt
```

I changed a little the names of your columns, which are not consistent between your sample data and results.

If any of your leaves spreads over more than 100 days, you need to add `option (maxrecusion 0)` at the very end of the query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00a43104ad616f56a040ab5ee1076c99)**:

Sample data:

```
slno | Emp_no | leave_appl_dt | From_dt    | To_dt      | no_of_days
---: | -----: | :------------ | :--------- | :--------- | ---------:
   1 |   1001 | 2020-01-01    | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-12 |         12
   2 |   1002 | 2020-01-10    | 2020-01-15 | 2020-01-25 |         10
```

Results:

```
leave_dt   | emp_no | leave_appl_dt
:--------- | -----: | :------------
2020-01-01 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-02 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-03 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-04 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-05 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-06 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-07 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-08 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-09 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-10 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-11 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-12 |   1001 | 2020-01-01   
2020-01-15 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-16 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-17 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-18 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-19 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-20 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-21 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-22 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-23 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-24 |   1002 | 2020-01-10   
2020-01-25 |   1002 | 2020-01-10
```

Comment: @arvindganur: this is a *recursive* query, that increments the leave date until the upper bound is met. I added a demo to my answer for your reference, this produces the results that you showed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a calendar table or tally/numbers table (highly recommended), you can use an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([slno] int,[Emp_no] int,[leave_appl_dt] date,[Fromdt] date,[Todate] date,[no_of_days] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,1001,'2020-01-01','2020-01-01','2020-01-12',12)
,(2,1002,'2020-01-10','2020-01-15','2020-01-25',10)

Select leavedt = b.D 
      ,A.Emp_no
      ,A.leave_appl_dt
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[Fromdt],[Todate])+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[Fromdt]) 
                From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
leavedt     Emp_no  leave_appl_dt
2020-01-01  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-02  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-03  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-04  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-05  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-06  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-07  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-08  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-09  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-10  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-11  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-12  1001    2020-01-01
2020-01-15  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-16  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-17  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-18  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-19  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-20  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-21  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-22  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-23  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-24  1002    2020-01-10
2020-01-25  1002    2020-01-10
```

Comment: Thank John, for understanding my question .

Answer (score -1):

You can use a numbers table :

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
    SET @Date1 = '20150528'
    SET @Date2 = '20150531'

SELECT 
      DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) [Date]
FROM 
      master..spt_values
WHERE 
      type = 'P' AND
      DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2
```

Comment: mis-use of `master..spt_values`?

Comment: Tq , i done this i need to match employees ID  and leave applied dates for all dates without passing employee number, i should do this for all  employee at one query.